# How to sample from a Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, distributions

**Edit 19-04-12**

I think the fewest words I could use to express this question would be "How do you sample from some PDFs p(x) and p(x) so as to produce the final image ([from here](https://medium.com/@cotra.marko/making-sense-of-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence-b0d57ee10e0a))?"

---

I've been working my way through [Marko Cotra's article on Kullback-Leibler Divergence](https://medium.com/@cotra.marko/making-sense-of-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence-b0d57ee10e0a) and it's helped me make the connection between distributions and how to express the differences between them/add them/sum them etc.

```
distP = NormalDistribution[];
distQ = GumbelDistribution[];
p[x_]:=PDF[distP, x]
q[x_]:=PDF[distQ,x]

(* this is the difference between distrobutions *)
Expectation[Log[p[x]/q[x]],x\[Distributed]distP]
(* Same as above *)
Integrate[p[x] Log[p[x]/q[x]],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
(* return the same *)
```

[image]

However, when I came upon the following image near the bottom of the page and tried to duplicate it in Mathematica 11.3, I found I was unable to do so. I assume it's because I'm missing something fundamental about probability theory and statistics. How do you sample a distribution in the form of P(X) to then generate the below graph?

[image]

Comment: I should probably add that this is in context of me working my way through Deep Learning
by Ian Goodfellow where on page 72 Kullback-Leibler Divergence is covered (with little help on how to recreate the above graph of sample p(x) in Mathematica.)

Comment: So - removing all the stuff that appears irrelevant to the direct question, are you asking "how does one sample from a normal distribution?" (per your example) or are you asking "what are the main methods by which people sample from distributions in general?" (an interesting question but one in danger of turning into a "big-list" question -- there are a lot of such methods, enough to quite literally fill books -- and risking closure as too broad, but which may already be addressed on site in spite of that)

Comment: Definitely asking specifically in this case, how do you sample from distribution of p(x) to then make a graph such as below? As one can imagine from posting on CV for fun, I have a lot of books on my shelf, but none which address the mechanics of sampling p(x) unfortunately. Hence my turning here help.

Comment: I'm confused by your return to the general case - p(x) - while calling it specific. Do you mean the specific normal case (as in the example)? [If you mean any p(x), that's general, not specific; but if you don't mean any p(x), why refer to it again in general terms as p(x) rather than as a normal distribution?] -- It seems like a simple question (if only I knew which one), but I fear I am missing something important now